# Lodash - Unshift with _.keys or _keysIn not working

Tags: lodash

With object like below:

```
var object = {
  a: 2,
  b: 6
};

var array _.keys(object).unshift('type');
var array1 _.keysIn(object).unshift('type');

console.log(array) // ['a', 'b'] and not ['type', 'a', 'b']
console.log(array1) // ['a', 'b'] and not ['type', 'a', 'b']
```

Any specific reason for this or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

[Array#unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) mutates the array, and return the new length. Create an array of keys, and unshift the `type` in another expression.

```js
var object = {
  a: 2,
  b: 6
};

var array = _.keys(object); // or Object.keys()

array.unshift('type');

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Another option is to use [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
var object = {
  a: 2,
  b: 6
};

var array = [].concat('type', Object.keys(object));

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lodash enables method chain sequences, either [implicitly](https://lodash.com/docs#lodash) or [explicitly](https://lodash.com/docs#chain).

Once the chaining is started, [you can use both Lodash and native Array methods](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#lodash), like so:

```js
var object = {
  a: 2,
  b: 6
};

var array = _
  .chain(object)
  .keys()
  .unshift('type')
  .value();

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

Since the result of such a chain sequence is not a single value or a primitive value (it's an array), you must use `value()` to unwrap it.